# Applying for a Schengen visa while visiting my family abroad

Tags: visa, eu

I am visiting my daughter’s place in USA who is a permanent resident. I have valid B-1 visa for the next 10 years. Can I apply for Schengen visa in USA to go Europe trip with my daughter's family?

Comment: @ManishaShah David asked about the main destination, not the port of entry.

Comment: Normally it must be applied in the country where you live. You will be a tourist in the US, so the chances of approval are low. I recently read a post on another forum where an Indian citizen applied for a Schengen visa (Netherlands) while on a holiday in Peru and got it. He posted that he talked to the embassy before applying and he had been traveling internationally for more than 6 months and was out of India for that long so the embassy accepted his application in Peru. Preferably, you should get it in your home country. If it is not possible, you try in the US but don't keep you hopes high

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks for the correction, I appreciate it. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @ThomasCruise Another reason for this may be found in Article 9(1) of the Visa Code: *Applications shall be lodged **no more than six months**, and ..., before the start of the intended visit, and, as a rule, no later than 15 calendar days before the start of the intended visit.*

Answer (score 3):

The Schengen Visa Code (article 6) provides that:

> 1. An application shall be examined and decided on by the consulate of the competent Member State in whose jurisdiction the applicant legally resides.

You are merely a visitor in the US and the general rule is therefore that you should apply from another location (a country where you are considered to be legally resident). If you look up the requirements to apply for a Schengen visa, you will often see something like “Original of valid US alien registration card (residence permit, aka: green card) or valid US resident visa.” As you cannot provide that, any application risks being very quickly declined.

The same article however also gives consulates some discretion to accept your application anyway:

> 2. A consulate of the competent Member State shall examine and decide on an application lodged by a third-country national legally present but not residing in its jurisdiction, if the applicant has provided justification for lodging the application at that consulate.

You could try to argue that the timing of your visit to the US did not let you apply before (as you are supposed to apply three to six months in advance). But there are no guarantees and in practice it will be difficult to pass the first filter (often an outsourcing provider like VFS Global).